# Наследование в Java

Tags: наследование, java

Здравствуйте!

Есть родительский класс Фигура и два ребенка - Круг и Квадрат. У фигуры есть метод рисовать(), который пока просто выводит "Нарисовали фигура".

Для того чтобы классы Круг и Квадрат выводили "Нарисовали круг" и "..квадрат", нужно полностью переназначать метод рисовать() в обоих классах или можно сделать это как-нибудь более правильно?

Спасибо

Comment: Правильно, конечно же, переназначить в наследниках.

Comment: @berbir, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[[@berbir](/users/28743/berbir)](/users/28743/berbir), очень сильно зависит от контекста. Какой-нибудь getInfoAsString() гарантированно возвращал бы строчку, в которой используется имя класса. Конкретно draw(), скорее всего, не лежал бы в этих классах вообще, потому что этим другой класс должен заниматься. С учетом того, что фигуры совершенно разные - у этого даже название какое-то есть, но я запамятовал - не рекомендуется делать единый обработчик для обоих (хотя можно задать в базовом классе этот базовый обработчик, который **рекомендуется** переопределить в наследниках, если они сильно различаются).

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к тому, что сказал @Etki. В Вашем случае можно вообще ничего не переопределять в классах наследниках. Т.к. 1-я часть вывода постоянна, а 2-я зависит от имени класса, то можно воспользоваться методами `getClass()` и `getSimpleName()`.
**Привожу реализацию:**

```
class Фигура {
    private static final String head = "Нарисовали ";

    protected void printBody(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase());
    }

    public void рисовать(){
        System.out.print(head); //print() не переводит на нов. строку,
        //в отличие от println()
        printBody();
    }
}

class Круг extends Фигура{
}

class Квадрат extends Фигура{    
}
```

**Пример использования:**

```
public class Main{
    /**
     * Выводит: 
     * Нарисовали круг
     * Нарисовали квадрат
     * Нарисовали фигура
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Круг().рисовать();
        new Квадрат().рисовать();
        new Фигура().рисовать();
    }
}
```

Я разбил реализацию вывода на 2 части. Поскольку слово *"Нарисовали"* скорее всего не будет меняться, то его я объявил как константу. Если же мы захотим для фигуры, например, треугольник, вывести *"Нарисовали **равносторонний** треугольник"*, нужно будет переопределить только метод `printBody()`.